# In Microsoft Azure, is there a way to look at a trigger to see which functions are called by it?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm guessing this has been asked before, but I haven't been able to find the answer... Is there a way to look at a trigger to see which functions are being started by it?

We are building functions that will be run on different timed triggers. We'd like to be able to see which ones set to the hourly trigger or the daily trigger (as an example).

Comment: For context... we are building functions that will be run on different timed triggers.  We'd like to be able to see which ones set to the hourly trigger or the daily trigger (as an example).

Comment: You can look at the function execution history to see how often it's being triggered.

Comment: You can see which function was triggered at what time from the history(As @Daniel mentioned), but you cannot see which function, that was triggered, was a daily , hourly etc from the history itself. For that you will need to go and check the schedule of the function that was triggered.

Comment: I appreciate the answers.  I don't think I phrased my question clearly enough.  The time component isn't really what I'm looking for (I was just stating our current use-case).  Say I have 5 triggers... T1, T2, T3, T4 and T5, and 100 various functions... I'm looking for a way to see which functions have been associated with a given trigger.  My team is new to Azure functions, so we're just trying to get a handle on some concepts/ideas that we haven't been able to answer ourselves.  This question has too many common key words for google to get me to what I'm asking without a ton of "static".

Comment: @Craig_Th Are you saying you have 5 timer-triggered functions, which then call *other* functions? Going into a bit more detail on your function app architecture in the body of your question would be useful here.

Comment: It was a much more general question... it has nothing to do with timers specifically (which is where my question sent folks down the wrong path in trying to answer).  I literally just wanted to know if I were to look at a given trigger... which functions are triggered by it.  After digging around, I did find a way to get to the answer though (see below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were finally able to find an answer to this question... Inside your DataFactory...

1. Go to Manage
2. Select Triggers
3. View the code for the trigger

The associated functions are shown under the pipelines as pipelineReferences

Answer (score -1):

Timer Trigger function is a non Http-Triggered Function & lets you run a function on a schedule based on the CORN Expression.

- You can look at the CRON expression which was  declared in the **function.json** file of a particular function.
- You can also refer the below documentation to get more understanding about the [corn expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-expressions).
- Alternatively, you can look at the logs of the function app based on the logs you validate which function is running at hourly basis & daily basis.
- You can refer the below [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68721632/azure-function-code-logs-info-in-first-azure-function-and-doesnt-logs-in-anothe/68768087#68768087) for more information about how to fetch the logs of a particular function under functionapp.